# Add current value of EditText to a set value

Tags: android, android-edittext

```
public void onClick(View v) 
{
  s.setText(s.getText().toString() + .5);
}
```

I want to have the value that is currently in s (EditText) to be .5 higher than it was before I clicked the button, I am a completely new to java and am unsure how to make this work. Any help is good help, Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**: as others have mentioned, doubles are usually better than floats.

getText().toString() needs to be turned into a numeric value before it's possible to add .5

```
try {
  double currentValue = Double.parseDouble(s.getText().toString())
  double newValue = currentValue + 0.5;
  s.setText(newValue.toString());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  // text in EditText was not a parsable number
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

float can cause unwanted representation. So if you want exact representation, try `BigDecimal`.

Modify your code

```
s.setText( new BigDecimal(s.getText().toString()).add(new BigDecimal( "0.5")).toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all use `Double.parseDouble()` method to convert string to double.

```
double val=Double.parseDouble(s.getText().toString()) + 0.5;
s.setText(String.valueOf(val);
```